# spark-submit fails while not connected to internet

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

When i try to submit a spark job with spark-submit with using argument --packages defined, i expect spark to search local repo for the artifacts first and use them if they exist.

I observe that every time spark tries to fetch the artifacts from internet and if you have no connection fails.

Can i force spark to use local cache only ?

example :

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.1.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql_2.11:2.1.1 my-assembly-1.1.0.jar /usr/local/path/config.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add required packages to `spark-defaults.conf` file located in `$SPARK_HOME/conf`. It will look in local-m2 for the packages. If packages are not in local-m2, it will try to download them from maven-central.
For example

```
spark.jars.packages   org.vegas-viz:vegas_2.11:0.3.11,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.1.0
```